# Initialize AWS EC2 machine with access keys on launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to launch an EC2 machine using aws cli.  I want several things to take place before I connect, including setting my configuration.

I successfully launch the machine using:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-062f7200baf2fa504 --count 1 \
--instance-type t2.micro --key-name MyFirstKey --security-group-ids \
launch-wizard-3 --user-data file://aws_setup_script.txt
```

my aws_setup_script.txt is

```
sudo yum update -y
aws configure set aws_access_key_id AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD
aws configure set aws_secret_access_key AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDDEEEEEFFFFFGGGGGHHHHH
aws configure set default.region us-east-1
```

`sudo yum update -y` successfully runs, but the `aws configure` steps do not.

Comment: Hopefully you haven't committed `aws_setup_script.txt` to a code repo. Also, no need for `sudo` in userdata - you are already running as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per best practice, It's always better to use the IAM instance role attached to your Ec2 instead of setting the AWS credentials within Ec2.

1. Create an IAM instance role ([refer AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html)) with the required permission want to give to Ec2.
2. Use `--iam-instance-profile` in aws cli command to attache the Ec2 with specific Iam role.

   ```
   aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-062f7200baf2fa504 --count 1 \
   --instance-type t2.micro --key-name MyFirstKey --security-group-ids \
   launch-wizard-3 --iam-instance-profile
   ```

Answer (score 2):

1. It is insecure passing secrets in user-data.
2. Your script is failing because it isn't running as `ec2-user` so it doesn't have `aws` in the path. Even if it worked, it wouldn't be configuring the CLI tool for the `ec2-user` account so it isn't going to work the way you want.
3. Most importantly, there is a much better way to accomplish this. You should be assigning an IAM instance profile to the instance. When you run the `aws` cli tool on an instance with an IAM role assigned it will automatically use those credentials.